# Why is it that one of these pictures I added is misaligned?

Tags: html, css

I've wanted to add some buttons to the site I'm working on, each to take you to another page. I just used images and added a hyperlink to them, and aligned them with using floats. I think it may be the text, but I'm not sure as I'm pretty new to using HTML and CSS. It turns out like this:
But it turns out like this:
[the last button from the left is misaligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzr2j.jpg)

My HTML type-up is here:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: url('realheckindoggopupper.png')
}

div {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 1px;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <body style="background-color:black">
    <h1 style="color:blue;text-size:50px;">Welcome to the Mamiya Mansion!</h1>
    <p style="color:white;">
      This is a place where I put all my thoughts. I talk about all my different interests here, from retrogaming, to retro-anime, linguistics, and philosophy. I don't have much here yet, more is on the way (including better CSS!), <br> but these buttons
      will allow you to access different parts I'm working on. </br>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <a href="retrostuff.html">
      <img src="retrostuff.png" style="width:100%;">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <a href="creations.html">
      <img src="creations.png" style="width:100%;">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <a href="pseudstuff.html">
      <img src="pseudstuff.png" style="width:100%;">
    </a>
    <div class="column">
      <a href="misc.html">
        <img src="misc.png" style="width:200%;">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: If you indent the code correctly, you'll notice more easily that you've put the last column div inside the previous one.

Answer (score 2):

As Guy Incognito pointed out in the comments, your final div is nested inside the previous. Try this instead:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <a href="retrostuff.html">
      <img src="retrostuff.png" style="width:100%;">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <a href="creations.html">
      <img src="creations.png" style="width:100%;">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <a href="pseudstuff.html">
      <img src="pseudstuff.png" style="width:100%;">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <a href="misc.html">
      <img src="misc.png" style="width:100%;">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah! I see how it is .Thanks.